# Как удалить с помощью php определнный текст до определенного символа

Tags: php

Как удалить текст **в каждой строчке кроме первой** до определенного символа-разделится ";", а лучше даже до например второго ";" и все после четвертого ";".

Пример:

```
Строка 0 - какой то текст (его трогать не надо)
Строка 1 - текст1;текст2;текст3;текст4;текст5
Строка 2 - текст6;текст7;текст8;текст9;текст10
```

Надо, чтобы осталось

```
Строка 0 - какой то текст (его трогать не надо)
Строка 1 - текст3;текст4
Строка 2 - текст8;текст9
```

Текст в каждой строке разный.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией explode(http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), она разбивает строку на массив и делит при помощи разделителя(в вашем случае ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос то думаю explode как сообщил @Quadra в связке с foreach

Примерно следующий код должен будет поправить CSV по вашему описанию... Если надо что бы колонки остались не тронутыми надо делать не срез(array_slice) а заполнять ненужные значения пустотой

P.S.: Лучше оперируйте тогда через фильтр нужными индексами

**UPD(по комментариям):**

```
$filePath = "/file.csv";
$text = file($filePath);
$newFile = [];
foreach($text AS $index => $line) {
    $args = explode(";", $line);
    $args = count($args) > 1 ? array_filter($args, function($value, $index) {

        if ($index == 2) {
            return str_replace(" ", "", $value);
        } elseif ($index == 3 || $index == 4) {
            return $value;
        }
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH) : $args;
    $args = implode($args, ";");
    $newFile[$index] = $args;
}
file_put_contents($filePath, implode($newFile, PHP_EOL), LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86976/discussion-on-answer-by-walfter-----php----).